# How to filter by path with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, ltree, sqlmodel

I have some resources in my database that are inherited to their sub-resources. I need to be able to get also the inherited resources when I query a resource. I have a field called `path` which I'm planning to use. The `path` always contains the full path of all resources related to the resource we are currently handling.

Example:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| id | res_id    | path                   |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 1  | res_1     | res_1                  |
| 2  | res_1.1   | res_1.res_1.1          |
| 3  | res_1.2   | res_1.res_1.2          |
| 4  | res_1.1.1 | res_1.res_1.1.res_1.1.1|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

If I query the `res_1.1`, I'd also have to get the `res_1` because it is the parent of `res_1.1`. And if I get the `res_1.1.1`, I'd have to get also rows 1 and 2 because they are included in the path of the `res_1.1.1`. Would love some advice how to do this with Postgres. I'm also using `sqlmodel` to write queries if that's important information.

**EDIT. My apologies for the vague introduction, the parameter `path` is already a [sqlalchemy Ltree](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html?highlight=Ltree#sqlalchemy_utils.primitives.ltree.Ltree) -field. I hope this makes things a bit simpler?**

Comment: To clarify, please disclose your actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script) and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Working with type `ltree`

Turns out you are working with the additional module [**`ltree`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html). And the dot (`.`) is your unambiguous delimiter. Assuming `path` is type **`ltree`** (you didn't clarify, yet) simplifies the task. There are [dedicated operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#LTREE-OP-TABLE) like:

> `ltree @> ltree` → `boolean`
>
> Is left argument an ancestor of right (or equal)?

So:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl_ltree t1   
JOIN   tbl_ltree t ON t.path @> t1.path
WHERE  t1.res_id = 'res_1_1_1';  -- your search term here
```

`ltree` also provides operator classes for a GiST index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_ltree_path_gist_idx ON tbl USING GIST (path);
```

.. which can be used by the above query. Plus, you'd have another B-tree index on `res_id`.

`res_id` is completely redundant and can be ignored or even dropped. We can work with another ltree operator on `path` instead:

> `ltree ~ lquery` → `boolean`
>
> Does ltree match lquery?

[About the `lquery` type.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.2)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_ltree   
WHERE  path @> (SELECT path FROM tbl_ltree WHERE path ~ '*.res_1_1_1'::lquery);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4595fb27760fa3909da1f96013006426)*

Only needs the GiST index.

#### Working with type `text`

While working with `text` instead of `ltree` (you didn't clarify, yet), here is one of many ways:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(string_to_array(path, '.')) AS res_id
   FROM   tbl_txt
   WHERE  res_id = 'res_1_1_1'  -- your search term here
   ) t1
JOIN  tbl_txt t USING (res_id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4595fb27760fa3909da1f96013006426)*

The subquery `t1` splits `path` into its building blocks. Then join to another instance of `tbl_txt`.

Comment: @lr_optim: To avoid time-consuming misunderstandings, please start any future Postgres question by disclosing the version in use and relevant table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using the LIKE predicate to find a row that partially matches `path`.
The query is:

```sql
SELECT t1.* FROM resources t1
WHERE
  (
    SELECT t2.path FROM resources t2
    WHERE t2.res_id = 'res_1.1'
  )
  LIKE t1.path||'%';
```

If `path` does not match correctly, add `.`.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM resources t1
WHERE
  (
    SELECT t2.path||'.' FROM resources t2
    WHERE t2.res_id = 'res_1.1'
  )
  LIKE t1.path||'.%';
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a6jGWYGs3RQoDCkRtsyJYg/0)